# Static generic function to check keyof prototype of typeof...?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a better way to do this? I'm trying to write a static factory function that takes two arguments: a generic object and a class type, and returns a new instance (or partial) of the class type given. What I want is to check that the generic object's properties don't violate the types or names of the public properties of the class.

Since it's a static function, I can't define the new return type in the factory class. So I'm trying to rely on accessing ['prototype'] as if it's an enum. Is this a sensible method? Also it seems I need to extend the typeof something for the compiler to have access to a 'prototype' property. I'm wondering if this could be written in some better way while keeping the import function static...?

```
export class emptyClass {
    //intentionally empty. Can we get rid of this somehow? If so, what would T extend?
}
export class Person {
    public id:number; 
    public name:string;
}

export class ImportObject<A> {
    public static ImportCastStatic<U,T extends typeof emptyClass>( 
            untypedObject:{[K in keyof T['prototype']]?:T['prototype'][K]}, 
            targetType:T)
            :T['prototype'] {
        let typedObject:T['prototype'] = <T['prototype']>new targetType();
        return (typedObject);
    }
}

export class Main {
    constructor() {
    //This is how I want to call it.
        let q = ImportObject.ImportCastStatic({name:"Alice",id:3}, Person);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd probably go about it:

```
// removing unused generic A from ImportObject<A>
export class ImportObject {
    // removing unused generic U from ImportCastStatic<U, T>
    // reinterpret T to be the instance type, not the constructor type
    public static ImportCastStatic<T>(
        untypedObject: Partial<T>, // Partial of T
        targetType: new () => T) // zero-arg constructor of T objects 
        : T {
        let typedObject = new targetType(); // no annotation/assertion required
        return Object.assign(typedObject, untypedObject); // do something with untypedObject
    }
}
```

The important bit here is that I changed your `T` to refer to the *instance* type instead of the *constructor* type.  Given `T`, you can describe the type of a zero-arg-constructor-of-`T`-objects via `new`able function-like type `new()=>T` (or `{new(): T}`).  You could have kept `T` as the constructor type, but then to refer to the instance type you'd have to do `T['prototype']` (which is fine) or use the [built-in](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1421-L1426) type alias `InstanceType<T>` (which might be better)... this is much more verbose and tedious code, though.  Better to have bare `T` multiple times and a single `new()=>T` than a single bare `T` and `InstanceType<T>` multiple times.

Less important but still noteworthy:

- I removed the `A` and `U` types since you weren't doing anything with them in your example code.  In general, unused generic parameters are a [bad idea](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---) and should be avoided.
- I assume you want to do *something* with `untypedObject`, right?  I merged its properties into the constructed `typedObject` via [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
- There's a [built-in](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1421-L1426) type alias called `Partial<T>` which is just the same as `{[K in keyof T]?: T[K]}`, so used it in place.
- Once you have `T` as the instance type, you don't have to annotate `typedObject` as `T` or assert that `new targetType()` is `T`.  The compiler will infer this from the known type of `typedObject` as a constructor function.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Wow - great answer! Awesome trick being able to run new() in the constructor... I'm wondering if that causes any kind of speed penalty as opposed to going for the ['prototype']? - but good to know both are okay. 

One issue is that what I'm actually doing inside here is calling a static function on type T... which I didn't include in my initial code. So this doesn't solve my exact issue (because now I have no handle on the typeof T), but it gives me good guidelines for how to write this cleanly. Marking it correct. Thank you!